# Mongo dB Query Filtering Techniques

Tags: mongodb

Any query techniques to filter below documents with below conditions?

```
{'_id':1, 'type_id':11,'tag':[]},
{'_id':2,'type_id':11,'tag':[]},
{'_id':5,'type_id':15,'tag':[]},
{'_id':3,'type_id':13,'tag':['like']},
{'_id':4,'type_id':13,'tag':[]}
```

I want to filter above documents with `type_id` is 11, 13 and only for `type_id` is 13, I need to check 'like' value in the tag array

**filter**

1. `type_id` is 11, 13
2. for `type_id` 13 must-have 'like' value in the tag
   array

Answer (score 0):

this is the query that you want

```
db.myCollection.find({ 
  $or: [{ type_id: 11 }, { type_id: 13, tag: { $in: ["like"] } }] 
})
```